# Loosing precision with dbGetQuery in ROracle

Tags: r, oracle, precision, roracle

I have recently started to use the package ROracle to exchange data between R and Oracle, but I have a precision problem when retrieving numbers with few decimal digits.
Here's an example:

```
#With library ROracle:
eval(canale)
out<-dbGetQuery(conRORA, "select 1.39 from dual")
dbDisconnect(conRORA)
[1] TRUE
#Printing the result with lots of digits, it seems fine:
print(out[1,],digits=10)
[1] 1.39
#but:
out[1,]-1.39
[1] 2.22044604925e-16
#why can't it be a perfect zero?

#if I do the same with library RODBC instead:
eval(chNew)
out2<-sqlQuery(channelNew,"select 1.39 from dual",dec=",")
out2[1,]-1.39
[1] 0
odbcCloseAll()
```

So, how can I have dbGetQuery to get the correct number of digits?
Thanks

Comment: Print it with 17 digits. Indeed, print the results from both ROracle and RODBC with 17 digits.

Comment: Ok, but I still wonder why ROracle doesn't use the same representation of numbers as R (while RODBC does). I know this may seem insignificant but it could give unexpected results when comparing numbers extracted from Oracle with others written in the console.